# Find first date of two consecutive weeks with records in R (data.table)

Tags: r, date, indexing, data.table

I'm trying to find the first date (per group) where there are records in one week as well as the next. Weeks don't start on Mondays but are defined as a seven-day period.

Assuming a date is the first day of the first week, I'm trying to test if the number of date records that fall in the second "week" is greater than one.

```
library(data.table)

dt=data.table(date=c(1,9,10,15,18,3,4,7,7,19,21,27),
              group=c(rep("a", 5), rep("b",7)))

> dt
    date group
 1:    1     a
 2:    9     a
 3:   10     a
 4:   15     a
 5:   18     a
 6:    3     b
 7:    4     b
 8:    7     b
 9:    7     b
10:   19     b
11:   21     b
12:   27     b
```

A for loop that would work on a data.frame looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(dt)

for(i in 1:length(df$date)){
  df$count[i] <- sum(df$date >= df$date[i] + 7 &
  df$date < df$date[i] + 14 &
  df$group == df$group[i])
}

> df
   date group  count
1     1     a      2
2     9     a      1
3    10     a      1
4    15     a      0
5    18     a      0
6     3     b      0
7     4     b      0
8     7     b      1
9     7     b      1
10   19     b      1
11   21     b      0
12   27     b      0
```

The first date per group where the count is greater than 0 would give me the start date of the first week, i.e. 1 in group "a" and 7 in group "b".

My real data.table has over ten million rows, so ideally I'd like a function that is similar to the above for-loop, so I can do something like this:

```
dt[, date/sum(date), by=group]
```

The problem is I don't understand how to create a function with indexing that works for a data.table. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain more about the `dt[, date/sum(date), by=group]`? What kind of output are you expecting? What is count for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this works:

```
# set the key for the rolling merges
setkey(dt, group, date)

# find start and end point of the intervals you want
start = dt[J(group, date + 7 ), .I, roll = -Inf, by = .EACHI]$I
end   = dt[J(group, date + 13), .I, roll =  Inf, by = .EACHI]$I

# if start is 0, the first condition is not satisfied, so set count to 0
dt[, count := (start != 0) * (end - start + 1)]

dt
#    date group count
# 1:    1     a     2
# 2:    9     a     1
# 3:   10     a     1
# 4:   15     a     0
# 5:   18     a     0
# 6:    3     b     0
# 7:    4     b     0
# 8:    7     b     1
# 9:    7     b     1
#10:   19     b     1
#11:   21     b     0
#12:   27     b     0
```

Comment: Recycling code from last year, unfortunately this solution no longer works. It throws an error: `Error in dt[J(group, date + 13), .I, roll = Inf]$.I : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`. I've used an (ugly) way to solve the problem with `foverlaps` (see my answer below). There must be a way to avoid the invalid operator error, but still use rolling joins?

Comment: @BramVisser fixed - error was (mostly) due to 1.9.4 making by-without-by explicit

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Thanks. I knew it was something simple like that and seem to remember the startup message saying something about .EACHI when importing data.table... Guess actually paying attention to these messages is a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the solution @eddi suggested no longer works with `R 3.1.2` and `data.table 1.9.4`. Failing with this error:

```
Error in dt[J(group, date + 13), .I, roll = Inf]$.I : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

The following code works, but is a quick and dirty workaround using the new `foverlaps` function. I'm sure that there must be a way to fix the rolling joins solution?

```
# Find start and end point of the intervals you want
dt[, start := date + 7]
dt[, end := date + 13]

# Make two data tables for overlapping dates.
dt2 <- dt[, c("group", "start", "end")]
dt[, date2 := date] # copy date (foverlaps need an interval).

# Sort by date and overlap-merge with week ranges.
setkey(dt, group, date, date2)
dt3 <- foverlaps(dt2, dt, by.x=c("group", "start", "end"))

# Count unique values to get number of records in following week.
setkey(dt, group, start, end)
setkey(dt3, group, i.start, i.end)
dt4 <- unique(dt)[dt3]
dt4[, count := ifelse(is.na(i.start), 0L, length(unique(i.start))), by=date]

# Cleaning up.
dt5 <- dt[unique(dt4)]
dt5 <- dt5[, c("date", "group", "count")]

# > dt5
#    date group count
# 1:    1     a     2
# 2:    9     a     1
# 3:   10     a     1
# 4:   15     a     0
# 5:   18     a     0
# 6:    3     b     0
# 7:    4     b     0
# 8:    7     b     1
# 9:    7     b     1
#10:   19     b     1
#11:   21     b     0
#12:   27     b     0
```

Very curious about the simple fix, if there is one.

Comment: Just remove the `$.I` at the end of that command. It already returns a vector. Go through the NEWS from v1.9.4 README.md file [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md) to get to know the changes.

Answer (score -1):

why not just use the loop you created?

```
dt[,count:=date]
for(i in 1:length(dt$date)){
    set(dt,i,3L, sum(dt$date >= dt$date[i] + 7 &
                           dt$date < dt$date[i] + 14 &
                           dt$group == dt$group[i]))
}
dt
#    date group count
# 1:    1     a     2
# 2:    9     a     1
# 3:   10     a     1
# 4:   15     a     0
# 5:   18     a     0
# 6:    3     b     0
# 7:    4     b     0
# 8:    7     b     1
# 9:    7     b     1
#10:   19     b     1
#11:   21     b     0
#12:   27     b     0
```

The way `by` works is similar to `tapply`. You spilt the `data.table` into mini data.tables by the variables in a column (e.g. group), perform a function over the entire mini data.table, returning something for each mini data.table, then combine the returned stuff to produce your output.